# How to exit a function, if a Search pattern found?

Tags: regex, vim, replace, regex-greedy

I have a function which contains certain search and replace pattern, like

```
function! SearchReplace()
%s/Search_string/\\new{Search_string}/g
%s/string/\\new{string}/g
endfunc
```

The o/p will \new{Search_\new{string}}. I need \new{Search_string} only.
Is there any way to exit the function, if any one of the pattern found

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could start with a call to `search()`, or test `v:errmsg`.

But, isn't your `string` a word?

```
:%s/\<string\>/\\new{string}/g
```

Beside, why two calls where one is enough?

```
%s/\v<(string|Search_string)>/\\new{\1}/g
```